# Which test to use for 2 groups with 2 subgroups each?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test, experiment-design, subset

I recorded the pumping rate of two types of worm: normal and mutant, with n=6 the number of worms per type.

Then, I exposed these types of worms to a drug. BUT I used a different batch of worms this time. So now we have normal + drug, and mutant + drug (n=6 each).
I wish to see how the drug affects the normal worm- so analyzing the difference between the pumping rates between mutant and normal when they are administered the drug.

Which test should I use? I was thinking ANOVA (one-way), or two sample t test, but I'm not sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally analyzed my data using the two-way ANOVA test, after checking for all assumptions (normality, homogeneity of variances, no outliers, etc.)
The factors were of worm type and drug condition. I then proceeded to multiple comparisons (Bonferroni's correction).